# Error de memoria al ejecutar un cierto comando

Tags: c++, string, socket

Vereis, tengo un pequeño problema al recibir datos desde un servidor con la informacion de los usuarios conectados en ese momento.
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui aparece el error al escribir un usuario demasiado largo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que da.

Codigo Servidor:

```cpp
void Server::SendUsers(std::shared_ptr<m_Connection> m_UserConnection) {
        std::string m_ListContainer;
        for(auto m_Connection : Server::m_connections) {
            m_ListContainer.append("[" + m_Connection->m_Username + "|" + std::to_string(m_Connection->m_ID) + "]");
        }
        m_PacketStructs::ChatMessage message(m_ListContainer);
        m_UserConnection->m_pm.Append(message.toPacket());
}
```

Codigo Cliente:

```cpp
std::string Client::GetUsers() {
    m_PacketStructs::m_UsersRequest m_RequestS("");
    m_pm.Append(m_RequestS.toPacket());
    std::string m_str;
    int32_t bufferlength;

    if(!Getint32_t(bufferlength))
        Log::Print("Failed Get Users", Log::m_Type::L_Error);

    if(bufferlength == 0) Log::Print("Failed Get Users", Log::m_Type::L_Error);
    ;
    m_str.resize(bufferlength);

    recvall(&m_str[0], bufferlength);

    return m_str;
}
```

Una cosita que me habia dejado es que al escribir el comando /List en la consola que llama a una funcion para enseñar todos los usuarios conectados, si algun usuario es demasiado largo da el error ese o aparece un abort() en la funcion de recv. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el error esta en m_str.resize pero no estoy del todo seguro.

Alguna idea de porque da ese error? He intentado convertir el m_str en un char* pero acaba dando el mismo problema.

Comment: has probado a depurar el programa? Yo dudo muchísimo que una función del estándar dé un error como el que comentas.

Comment: @eferion Si, he probado a depurar el programa pero sigue sin darme ninguna respuesta sobre que pasa con el problema de los usuarios. He visto que si ejecuto el programa linea por linea nisiquiera recibe los paquetes correspondientes y valor de bufferlength es un numero inmenso.

Comment: Para nada creo que el problema sea alguna funcion del std, sino de mi codigo pero no veo donde puede estar y a ver si alguien consigue verlo y mostrarmelo.

Comment: Pues entonces deberías mirar por qué `bufferlength` tiene esos valores

Comment: Pero quién posiciona `bufferlength`? Nadie. No lo inicializas, y llamas a una función que curiosamente se llama `GetIn32_t` a la que parece que le pasas `bufferlength` por **valor**. Si esa es la función que supuestamente tiene que dar valor a `bufferlength`, va a ser que no le da ningún valor, y `bufferlength` tendrá un valor aleatorio.

Comment: De hecho, estoy pasando bufferlenght por referencia, y si el valor es correcto a la hora de recibir el mensaje aunque ya lo he arreglado de otra forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bufferlength`no está inicializado. La única oportunidad sería que `GetInt32_t` lo aceptase por referencia y le diera valor, pero al no admitir más parámetros no tiene mucho sentido.

En resumen, parece que tienes una variable sin inicializar que utilizas para reservar un bloque de memoria. Si por casualidad la variable tiene un valor muy alto, acabarás con esa excepción, debida seguramente a la imposibilidad de reservar la cantidad de memoria solicitada.